# Rails5. Nested attributes are not going to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  .... // some filed here everything fine
  <%= f.fields_for :address do |a| %>
     <%= a.text_field :city %> // this field is not appear
  <% end %>
<% end %>

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.valid?
      @user.save
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:id, :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :status, :image, :address_attributes => [:id, :city, :street, :home_number, :post_code, :country])
    end
end
```

So like you can see above I have two classes and one form, when I am trying display fields for Address class I can not do it in that way. I took this example from https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for
I was trying different combination like for example using User.new and Address.new in form definition it not working as well, I was able display all fields in that situation but I wasn't able to save Address data to table, because of "unpermited address".

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? Or at least give me please some hints.

[SOLVED]
I should learn how to read documentations properly. Excalty like @Srack said I needed just use build_address method. I checked documentation rails api again and on the end of page there was examples says to create User class like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
  def address
    super || build_address
  end
end
```

and that solved my issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey - I've added an answer for what I believe to be the initial problem - would you mind posting the params as they arrive in the controller for when you're hitting the `unpermited address` error? I'd imagine it's the same issue, in that the address doesn't belong to the user, but that'll let us know :)

Comment: How does the HTML look like? Is the text field with the city named "user[address_attributes][city]"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to make sure there's an `address` instantiated for the user in the `new` view. You could do something like:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.build_address
end
```

You should then see the address fields on the form.

The `nested_fields_for` show the fields for a record that's been initialised *and* belong to the parent. I think the latter is why your previous attempts haven't worked.

FYI `build_address` is an method generated by the `belongs_to` association: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-belongs-to

Comment: You help me in 50%, I can display fields and I see in console like I am saving data to address table(that doesn't happen before), but I am inserting just user_id, create_at and update_at. To achieve that my nested form now looks like:
    <%= fileds_for :address, @user.address do |a| %>
When I add "f" on front of fileds_for can not display fields from address. The same things happen if remove :address.

Comment: My html looks like address["city"] and when I do request I am sending 
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rzXQwxks/sXjYTpuJ7VHGC5FClV21mFzDktcFBYbVbr5A9Ln76wlNnVmPfLsKMtGJKauyj+UOi+GzktDV+FzhA==", "user"=>{"name"=>"asd", "email"=>"asd@asd.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "address"=>{"city"=>"a", "street"=>"a", "home_number"=>"2", "post_code"=>"a", "country"=>"United Kingdom"}, "commit"=>"Dołącz do nas"}